# bigquery concurrency for analytical queries

Tags: concurrency, google-bigquery

I have a complex query which when run by itself takes about 10 minutes in bigquery. The time increases to 40 minutes if the same 10 are run concurrently. It goes to 2 hrs if the same 25 are run concurrently. We are evaluating bigquery for analytical platform and wondering if something could be done to help with concurrency.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: i second above. plus - still would consider "fixing" 40 min long-running query in first place :o)

Comment: The topic on [Query Plan Explanation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation) is good reading, as is [Optimizing Query Computation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute), too.